# firebase notification events not working in service worker (notifcationclose, notificationclick)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to send web push notifications with my react app, using firebase. I have succeeded in getting the notification to appear, but i want the notification to 1. persist until interacted with (requireInteraction) and 2. open a link when clicked (click_action). requireInteraction works when sending a data message instead of a notification message, but i cannot get the link opening to work.

In my service worker file (firebase-messaging-sw.js), i am trying to register event listeners for the "notificationclick" and "notificationclose" events, where i would handle the link opening. But none of those events get triggered when they are supposed to. I have tried registering the event listener before importing the scripts, before initializing firebase.messaging() as suggested by people who have had the same problem, but nothing works.

One thing to note is that sometimes, the notificationclose event does trigger, but randomly and without me interacting with the notification, and it gets triggered multiple times. It seems like the event gets backed up for some reason and then at random times triggers all at once. I have tried to recreate the event being fired without success, it happens randomly. (see screenshot of console output)

[image: console output of service worker]

This is my current code (firebase-messaging-sw.js):

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", console.log);

self.addEventListener("notificationclose", console.log);

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const config = {
  apiKey: "(redacted)",
  authDomain: "(redacted)",
  databaseURL: "(redacted)",
  projectId: "(redacted)",
  storageBucket: "(redacted)",
  messagingSenderId: "(redacted)",
  appId: "(redacted)",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log("fdgdfgdfgh"); //got message event
  return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title,
      Object.assign({data: payload.data}, payload.data));
});
```

and this is where i send the fcm request:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require('../../firebasekey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  projectId: "(redacted)",
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

var message = {
    "data": {
      "title": "Rapportera för TEST",
      "body": "Klicka här för att komma till rapporten",
      "requireInteraction": "true",
      "icon": "http://localhost:3000/notificon.png",
      "click_action": "http://google.com",
    },
    token: "(redacted)",
  };
  
  admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
      // Response is a message ID string.
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was windows 10's native notifications. Disabling native notifications in chrome flags fixed it for me, you'll have to deal with uglier notifications but they work.

```
chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense, then why do all other websites' notification click work?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the push notification click will only go to the website that the notification is triggered for. For example, your site is https://example.com then if you give the url in `click_action` like http://google.com then it will not work. give it like `/some-page-in-your-website`. so that when you click on the notification you'll be redirected to `https://example.com/some-page-in-your-website`. Also your website should be served through https.

```
var message = {
    "data": {
      "title": "Rapportera för TEST",
      "body": "Klicka här för att komma till rapporten",
      "requireInteraction": "true",
      "icon": "https://example.com/images/notificon.png",
      "click_action": "/page-in-your-website",
    },
    token: "(redacted)",
  };
```